# Implementing stack using generic pointer in c

Tags: c, generics

This is my code for implementing stack using generic pointer, I am not getting the proper  output, at the time of display, sometimes I am getting garbage value, there is also a problem while popping the value.

I took `void *data` as generic pointer and I have to pass `int` and `float` values to it , I have used `memmove` to move the address of local variables of `int` and `float` to pass the address to the generic pointer .

I am new with generic pointers and implemented it first time. I just cant find out whats the problem .

If anybody could solve my problem than  it would be great help.
Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>

static int position = 0;


typedef struct generic
{
    void *data;
    struct generic *next;
} generic;


generic *pop(generic *top);


generic *
push (generic *top, void *temp, int size)
{
    generic *nw;
    nw = (generic *) malloc (sizeof (generic));
    nw->data = malloc(size);
    memmove(nw->data, temp, size);
    nw->next = top;
    return nw;
}

generic *
pop (generic *top)
{
    generic *p;
    if (top == NULL)
        printf ("\n Stack is empty");
    else
    {
        p = top->next;
        free(top->data);
        free (top);
        top = p;
        position--;
        return top;
    }
}



void
display (generic *top, int temp[])
{
    int pos = 0;
    for (; top != NULL; top = top->next)
    {
        if (temp[pos] == 1)
            printf ("\n %d", *(int *) top->data);
        else
            printf ("\n %.2f", *(float *) top->data);
        pos++;
    }
}




int
main ()
{
    generic *top = NULL;
    int choice;


    bool exitt = false;
    int temp[5];
    while(1)
    {
        printf ("\n*******Stack using generic pointer*********\n");
        printf ("\n 1.PUSH");
        printf ("\n 2.POP");
        printf ("\n 3.DISPLAY");
        printf ("\n 4.EXIT");
        printf ("\n********************************************\n");

        printf ("\n enter the choice");
        scanf ("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            int choose;
            printf("Enter the choose option\n");
            scanf("%d", &choose);
            if (choose == 1)
            {
                int val;
                printf ("\nenter the value");
                scanf ("%d", &val);
                top = push (top, &val, sizeof(val));
                temp[position++] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                float val;
                printf ("\nenter the value");
                scanf ("%f", &val);
                top = push (top, &val, sizeof(val));
                temp[position++] = 2;

            }
            break;

        case 2:
            top = pop (top);
            break;

        case 3:
            display (top, temp);
            break;
        default :
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give the **exact** test input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Why does `pop` modify `position` but `push` doesn't?

Comment: One problem: `pop` does not return anything for the empty case. It should return NULL.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He modifies `position` outside the function `pop`, which is not a great idea... But it's also not the reason for his problem.

Comment: @kaylum The output is wrong when he tries to push different datatypes (`float` *and* `int`) to the same stack. I have explained why that's the case in my answer.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang I know the code does that. I'm asking *why*. I'm not convinced it's not the reason for his problem, and I have a hunch if I hear the OP's explanation for *why* it does that, I'll understand the OP's issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are saying that you are *"not convinced it's not the reason for his problem"*... But I have provided a fix for the actual problem in my answer and the fact that he doesn't modify `position` in the function `pop` doesn't have anything to do with the fix.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang I feel like we're talking past each other. I am *not* saying that the fact that he doesn't modify `position` in `pop` has something to do with the fix. I'm saying that *WHY* he doesn't modify `position` in `pop` may have something to do with the problem. But we'll never find out if I'm right if the OP doesn't answer my question -- *why* did the OP write the code that way?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think I know why he did it outside `pop`. The problem is he has to initialize the array at `temp[position]` and *then* increase `position` by one. This can easily be done with `temp[position++] = 2;`, but wouldn't be that easy inside the function `pop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the function `pop` has to return something if `top == NULL`, as [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum) pointed out in the comments.

```
if (top == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: stack is empty\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Note that you also don't need to cast `malloc`, because it returns `void *`, which is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer.

```
nw = malloc(sizeof(generic)); /* no need to cast malloc */
```

## Your approach

If you want to stick to your approach, I would store the return value of `sizeof()` in the `site_t` datatype.

```
push (generic *top, void *temp, size_t size) { }
```

And the thing that actually causes your problem is the fact that you iterate over the array `temp` from `0` to `position - 1` while the elements on the stack are in reverse order. This code should work though:

```
void display (generic *top, int temp[])
{
    for (; top != NULL; top = top->next) {
        position--; // <- the global variable
        if (temp[position] == 1)
            printf("%d\n", *(int *) top->data);
        else
            printf("%.2f\n", *(float *) top->data);
    }
}
```

## Alternative solution

I would store the data in a `union` instead of a generic `void` pointer, as briefly described in [Paul Ogilvie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66949709/14947044), because with your approach you have to keep track of the datatype outside, which is generally not a good idea.

### C11 and newer

As of [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) the `union` can be anonymous:

```
enum datatype {
    DATATYPE_INT,
    DATATYPE_FLOAT,
}

struct generic {
    enum datatype;
    union {
        int int_data;
        float float_data;
    };
    struct generic *next;
};
```

The data can then be accessed like this:

```
if (top->datatype == DATATYPE_INT)
    printf("%d\n", top->int_data);
else if (top->datatype == DATATYPE_FLOAT)
    printf("%f\n", top->float_data);
```

### C99 and older

If you are using [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or older you have to name the `union`.

```
enum datatype {
    DATATYPE_INT,
    DATATYPE_FLOAT,
}

struct generic {
    enum datatype;
    union {
        int int_data;
        float float_data;
    } data;
    struct generic *next;
};
```

The data can then be accessed like this:

```
if (top->datatype == DATATYPE_INT)
    printf("%d\n", top->data.int_data);
else if (top->datatype == DATATYPE_FLOAT)
    printf("%f\n", top->data.float_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer.

I suggest you use a `union`, for example:

```
typedef struct generic
{
    int datatype;
    union {
        int intval;
        float floatval;
    }u;
    struct generic *next;
} generic;
```

Now you can store the type of the data with the data and do not need to keep track of it outside your data structure.

Comment: As of C11 the `union` may even be anonymous. And I would also suggest declaring an `enum` for the datatype.

Comment: Thank you every one the program is working now, there was a mistake at time of displaying... I used pos as zero it should be position-1 and traverse it from reverse order pos--.